# Passing data to server showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, ajax, flux

i'm new at React JS and Flux, i want to pass my data from my React form to my server, in the server i have a code to send an email, i'm using a flux architecture. When i run my code it work properly, only the data is undefined. Can anyone help me? Here is my code

This is my Store.js

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

import Dispatcher from '../dispatcher/Dispatcher';

import MessageConstants from '../constants/MessageConstants';


class MessageStore extends EventEmitter{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.supportTicket = [
            {
                fullName: '',
                site: '',
                email: '',
                subject: '',
                description: '',
                type: ''
            }
        ];
    }
    sendMessage(fullName, site, email, subject, description, type){
        this.supportTicket.push({
            fullName,
            site,
            email,
            subject,
            description,
            type
        });
        this.emit("change");
    }
}

const MessageStore = new MessageStore;
Dispatcher.register(function(action) {
    switch (action.actionType) {
        case MessageConstants.PERFORM_SEND_MESSAGE:
            this.sendMessage(action.fullName, action.site, action.email, action.subject, action.description)
            break;
            default:
                // no op
    }
});
export default MessageStore;
```

this is action.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

import Dispatcher from '../dispatcher/Dispatcher';
import MessageConstants from '../constants/MessageConstants';


function sendMessage(fullName, site, email, subject, description, type, callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/v1/supportTicket',
    contentType: 'aplication/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      fullName: fullName,
      site: site,
      email: email,
      subject: subject,
      description: description,
      type
    })
  })
  .done(function(sendMessage) {
    callback(null, sendMessage);
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    console.error('Failed to send message', JSON.stringify(err));
    callback(err);
  });
}
const MessageActions = {
  sendMessage: function(fullName, site, email, subject, description, callback) {
    sendMessage(fullName, site, email, subject, description, function(err, fullName, site, email, subject, description, type) {
      if(err) { return callback(err); }
      Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: MessageConstants.PERFORM_SEND_MESSAGE,
        fullName: fullName,
        site: site,
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        description: description,
        type: type
      });
      callback(null, fullName)
    });
  }
};

module.exports = MessageActions;
```

and this is my method for handle a submit data

```
handleSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        
        this.handleProfileChange();
        // this.handleSubjectChange(evt);
        // this.handleMessageChange(evt);
        // var messageInfo = {
        //     subject: this.state.subject,
        //     description: this.state.description
        // };
        
        console.log(this.state.fullName);
        console.log(this.state.site);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(this.state.subject);
        console.log(this.state.description);
        this.setState({ submitting: true }, () => {
            MessageActions.sendMessage(this.state.fullName, this.state.site, this.state.email, this.state.subject, this.state.description, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    this.setState({
                        submitting: false,
                        errorMessage: errorText(err)
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

and this is for my backend

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const email = require('nodemailer');

const routing = requirerp('/lib/routing');
const Err = requirerp('/utils/restErrors');

//let account = await email.createTestAccount();
let transporter = email.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        pass: 'xxxxx'
    }
        
});


router.post('/', routing.requireAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    var fullName = req.body.fullName
    var site = req.body.site
    var email = req.body.email
    var subject = req.body.subject
    var description = req.body.description
    var type = req.body.type
    var content = 'Nama : ' + fullName + '\nLokasi : ' + site + '\nPesan : ' + description

    let mailOptions = {
        from: fullName + '<' + email + '>',
        to: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Request :' + subject,
        text: content
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
        if(Err.invalidInput(next, err)) {
            return;
            console.log('Error' + info);
        }
        else {
            res.json({
                status: 'success'
            })
            console.log('Email has been sent' + info.response);
        }
    })
})
    

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in backend part something like this:

```
const myObj = req.body.data
var fullName = myObj.fullName
var site = myObj.site
...
```

Comment: It's not made a changes, a data still showing undefined. Should i restart a server before i try to run my code again?

Comment: Ok, i have changed a code, and restrart the server but it still, undefined, and get some more error, any suggestion?